# Sample size calculation for 3 groups?

Tags: anova, sample-size, statistical-power

I want to determine the sample size necessary in a study of 3 different treatment groups using a one-way ANOVA. The clinically significant difference here is +/- 10.

When entering means into a program (I have both PASS and G*Power), should I be entering something like 120, 110, 130?  I'm getting very small sample sizes as a result (n=6 per group) and want to make sure that I am doing this correctly.

Comment: What value of the error variance are you providing to these programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an estimated standard deviation of $\sigma = 5,$ for a three-group, one-way ANOVA with normal data, $n = 6$ replications in each group would give reasonable power (at significance level 5%) detecting inter-group differences of about 10. (That's for differences about double the standard deviation.)

Here are power curves from Minitab 17.

[image]